# check the string is Base64 encoded in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, base64

I am using PowerShell to make a condition selection, need to judge whether the string is Base64 encoded,

What is the easiest and most direct way?

```
            if ($item -is [?base64])
            {
                # handle strings or characters
            }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397185/powershell-determine-base64-string-file-extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following **returns `$true` if `$item` contains a valid Base64-encoded string**, and `$false` otherwise:

```
try { $null=[Convert]::FromBase64String($item); $true } catch { $false }
```

- The above uses [`System.Convert.FromBase64String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Convert.FromBase64String) to try to convert input string `$item` to the array of bytes it represents.
- If the call succeeds, the output byte array is ignored (`$null = ...`), and `$true` is output.
- Otherwise, the `catch` block is entered and `$false` is returned.

**Caveat**: **Even regular strings can *accidentally* be technically valid Base64-encoded strings**, namely if they happen to contain only characters from the Base64 character set and the character count is a multiple of 4.
For instance, the above test yields `$true` for `"word"` (only Base64 chars., and a multiple of 4), but not for `"words"` (not multiple of 4 chars.)

---

For example, in the context of an `if` statement:

- Note: In order for a `try` / `catch` *statement* to serve as an *expression* in the `if` conditional, `$()`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), must be used.

```sh
# Process 2 sample strings, one Base64-encoded, the other not.
foreach ($item in 'foo', 'SGFwcHkgSG9saWRheXM=') {

  if ($(try { $null=[Convert]::FromBase64String($item); $true } catch { $false })) {
    'Base64-encoded: [{0}]; decoded as UTF-8: [{1}]' -f
       $item,
       [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($item))
  }
  else {
    'NOT Base64-encoded: [{0}]' -f $item
  }

}
```

The above yields:

```
NOT Base64-encoded: [foo]
Base64-encoded: [SGFwcHkgSG9saWRheXM=]; decoded as UTF-8: [Happy Holidays]
```

---

It's easy to wrap the functionality in a custom **helper function**, **`Test-Base64`**:

```sh
# Define function.
# Accepts either a single string argument or multiple strings via the pipeline.
function Test-Base64 {
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] 
    [string] $String
  )
  process {
    try { $null=[Convert]::FromBase64String($String); $true } catch { $false }
  }
}

# Test two sample strings.
foreach ($item in 'foo', 'SGFwcHkgSG9saWRheXM=') {
  if (Test-Base64 $item) {
    "YES: $item"
  }
  else {
    "NO: $item"
  }
}
```

---

For information on **converting bytes to and from Base64-encoded strings**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55680423/45375).